# How to define inode_operation for proc_dir_entry?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, procfs

I'm trying to learn how to write linux kernel module using **The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide**

However I realized that the examples in this book are quite obsolete. 
Following is one of the examples from the book.

```
static struct proc_dir_entry *Our_Proc_File;
static int module_permission(struct inode *inode, int op, struct nameidata *nd)
{

    if (op == 4 || (op == 2 && current−>euid == 0))
            return 0;
    return −EACCES;
}
static struct inode_operations Inode_Ops_4_Our_Proc_File = {
    .permission = module_permission
}
static struct file_operations File_Ops_4_Our_Proc_File = {
    // ... 
};

int init_module()
{
    Our_Proc_File = create_proc_entry(PROC_ENTRY_FILENAME, 0644, NULL);
    // above line should use proc_create() 
    if (Our_Proc_File == NULL) {
            remove_proc_entry(PROC_ENTRY_FILENAME, &proc_root);
            return −ENOMEM;
    }

    Our_Proc_File−>owner = THIS_MODULE;
    Our_Proc_File−>proc_iops = &Inode_Ops_4_Our_Proc_File;
    Our_Proc_File−>proc_fops = &File_Ops_4_Our_Proc_File;
}
```

When I looked through the source code, I found that `proc_iops` was being removed from the `proc_dir_entry` structure in Linux 4.x

So How should I define the `inode_operations` for the `proc_dir_entry`

Comment: Field `proc_iops` is still exists in `struct proc_dir_entry`, see [fs/proc/internal.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/internal.h?v=4.9). The other thing, that given struct shouldn't be accessed by outer code, that is why it is defined in "internal" header. General idea of `/proc` filesystem is to give kernel and its modules ability to easily create **files** with "content" generated on the fly and directories for **group** these files. Leaving inodes and dentries to the kernel. If you want specific **inode** operations, implement your own filesystem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you so much! Can you put this into answer section ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General purpose of `/proc` filesystem is to give kernel and its modules ability to easily create **files** with "content" generated on the fly **and** directories for **group** these files. One may do that by using `proc_create()` and friends.

As for inodes and dentries, they are part of filesystem's *internals*: it is better to not modify them and their operations.

Actually, `file_operations` are powerful by themselves. If you find `mode` parameter for `proc_create()` insufficient to reflect access rights, you may check access in `.open()` *file operation*.

---

As for the field `proc_iops` in struct `proc_dir_entry`, it is still exist. But the structure itself is defined in *internal* header `fs/proc/internal.h` - another signal, that accessing its fields from outside is not expected.